# Storm-React-Diagram Demo custom link 1

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Expected outcome:
I was trying to to achieve this feature using storm react diagram. (click this [link](http://projectstorm.cloud/react-diagrams/?path=/story/advanced-techniques--smart-routing) to show demo)

The Desired outcome:
convert the TypeScript to JavaScript should work, but it keep having error.

Problem:
however I ran into an error when converting this typescript to JavaScript (see below code block)

```
    import * as SRD from 'storm-react-diagrams';
    
    // setup diagram engine
    this.engine = new SRD.DiagramEngine();
    this.engine.installDefaultFactories();
    
    //      
    const pathfinding = this.engine.getLinkFactories().getFactory<SRD.PathFindingLinkFactory>SRD.PathFindingLinkFactory.NAME;
```

What I have tried,

```
const pathfinding = this.engine.getLinkFactories().getFactory(PathFindingLinkFactory.NAME);
```

but I got this error instead

[image]

Full disclosure, I have [posted this on GitHub too](https://github.com/projectstorm/react-diagrams/issues/690#issuecomment-664758192).

Comment: Stack Overflow is not for advertising your bug reports elsewhere. The idea here is that you post everything that the reader would need to know, in the question itself. That means that the question will survive even if the link is altered or deleted (and thus that any answers given are not a wasted effort). The point of Stack Overflow is produce a high-quality set of Q&A, in order to help future readers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved.

const pathfinding = this.engine.getLinkFactories()[PathFindingLinkFactory.NAME];